# DocumentDb cannot handle @ in column (coming from attribute data in Xml) names for searching but save works

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am saving this following XML to DocumentDB:

```
<DocumentDbTest_Countries country="C25103657983" language="C25103657983" countryCode="383388823" version="2015-08-25T08:36:59:982.3552" />
```

Which gets saved fine to the DocumentDB as following:

```
{
"DocumentDbTest_Countries": {
     "@country": "C25103657983",
     "@language": "C25103657983",
     "@countryCode": 383388823,
     "@version": "2015-08-25T08:36:59:982.3552"
},
"id": "f917945d-eaee-4eff-944d-dae366de7be1"
}
```

As you can see the column name is indeed saved with the @ in it in the DocumentDB (without any kind of errors/exceptions/warning apparently) but then when I try to do a lookup it fails in the *Query Explorer*. It seems there is no way to search on @ column names. Is this true? or, am I missing something? Can someone please point me to a documentation about this limitation somewhere??

Comment: Deb, did my answer below serve? If so, can you please accept the answer.

Comment: Hey @LarryMaccherone, no not really - you answer was not working.
But another user Laan (in my another query about the use of hyphen) helped me instead in another direction.

As it turns out I have to use the *CollectionName.DocumentName* to do the search instead - and simply doing a search on the document name won't work somehow.

So this works:
SELECT * FROM TestProject.DocumentDbTest_Countries c
where c["@country"] != ""

[Proof image](http://i.imgur.com/vu0cNBU.png)

But then I miss the Document.Id and Document.SelfLink data in the return. :(

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as on your other question but if you replace `c["@country"]` with `c["DocumentDbTest_Countries"]["@country"]` then you can go back to just `SELECT * FROM TestProject c WHERE ....` I'll edit my answer below to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

For field names that use certain characters (space, "@", "-", etc.) or which conflict with SQL keywords, you have to use quoted property accessor syntax. So instead of writing:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.DocumentDbTest_Countries.@something = 10
```

write:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c["DocumentDbTest_Countries"]["@something"] = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the trick was to use **CollectionName.DocumentName** instead of just the **DocumentName**, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TestProject.DocumentDbTest_Countries c where c["@country"] = "C26092630539"
```

[image: Proof image]

But then I miss the Document.Id and Document.SelfLink data in the return Document data.

Comment: how is this different to the answer provided by @Larry ?